# How to cross-reference items in description lists?

Tags: lists, cross-referencing, description

Every now and then I use the description list environment

```
\begin{description}
\item[foo]  foo is good
\item[bar]  bar is bad
\end{description}
```

to create lists with non-numerical labels. Unfortunately the description list does not support the label-reference pair as normal latex: i.e. if I write

```
\begin{description}
\item[foo] \label{foo} foo is good
....
\end{description}
....
For good things (see, for example \ref{foo})...
```

the reference does not point to the item in the list. Instead it points to the closest environment that supports labeling (usually the subsection). So instead of showing the text foo (in boldface), it shows something like 2.2.1 (the subsection corresponding to where the description environment is sitting).

My question: is there a way or a package which allows references to description list items? My current work-around is to just type the text myself in the spot (since I named it myself, and it is not numbered, the formatting is unlikely to change the label =). But one of the good things about the label/reference pairs in latex is the implementation in pdflatex that allows in PDF hyperlinks between references and the objects referred to, this I cannot replicate myself.

**Edit**: let me rephrase my question. The primary goal is *not* to display `\ref` to something other than what LaTeX thinks the `\label` is. There are many ways to deal with it, some of which outlined in Michael Underwood's helpful answer below. What I am looking at is whether there exists an implementation of a list environment which is like the built-in `description` environment in that the displayed "title" for the list item is completely customized, while having support for `\label`s. (The built-in `description` environment does not support `\label`s, whereas the built-in `enumerate` environment does not support customized "title"s.) The `enumitem` package adds some customizability to the environments, but as far as I can tell it doesn't support exactly what I want.

Comment: @willie-wong If you think that his answer is "helpful," doesn't it deserve your upvote?

Comment: Should an upvote be given to a generically helpful answer that does not address the question asked at all? He accurately described the work-around I alluded to in my question, but did not provide an answer to the specific question asked. So no, I don't think it deserve an upvote.

Comment: His second answer however, is wonderful. I'll vote for that once my vote limit cap is cleared in a few hours.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know of a pre-built package that allows you to do this, but if I correctly understand what you're after then it is achievable by combining a counter with custom commands and the `hyperref` package.  The first step is to create a new counter for the described items, and a pair of new commands to use in place of `\item` and `\ref`.  In the preamble, put the following:

```
\newcounter{desccount}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
  \item[#1] \refstepcounter{desccount}\label{#1}
}
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{#1}}
```

The new command `\descitem` is to be used in place of `\item` within a `description` environment.  It takes a single argument and creates an item labeled with it.  It also increments the new counter, sets it as the current value for the `\ref` command, and labels the location with the item's descriptor.  The new command `\descref` takes the same argument and makes a hyperlink reference to the label, displaying the argument instead of the counter's value.

The commands work together like this:

```
\begin{description}
  \descitem{foo} foo is good
  \descitem{bar} bar is bad
\end{description}
...
For good things (see, for example \descref{foo})...
```

Comment: Sweet. Just tried it out and it works well. Ideally I would have liked to have the key and the displayed label possibly different, but I think I know roughly how to hack it to a way that works. (I'll up-vote this answer in a bit; I've hit my daily vote limit so cannot vote right now.)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after Michael's second answer I had an idea which I want to just document here. Instead of using the `description` environment, it seems that another way is to abuse the `list` environment. The following snipplet is what can be done

```
\newcounter{foobarcounter}
\renewcommand{\thefoobarcounter}
      {({\ifcase\value{foobarcounter}\or foo\or bar\else ehhh\fi\relax})}
\begin{list}{\thefoobarcounter}{\usecounter{foobarcounter}}
 \item\label{foodesc} Foo is good
 \item Bar is bad
 \item This list was not supposed to be this long
\end{list}
......
.. Something good, see \ref{foodesc}.
```

Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty approach could be patching the underlying `\@item`-command to also place a `\phantomsection`, i.e., an anchor for hyperlinks, and to redefine `\@currentlabel` to expand to the content of the optional argument.

With this approach please don't use the `\label`-command inside the optional argument of `\item` within the `mydescription`-environment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@saved@item{}
\newcommand\mydescriptionitem{}
\def\mydescriptionitem[#1]{%
  \my@saved@item[{\csname phantomsection\endcsname#1}]%
  \def\@currentlabel{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
}%
\newenvironment{mydescription}%
               {%
                  \let\my@saved@item=\@item
                  \let\@item=\mydescriptionitem
                  \description
               }%
               {\csname enddescription\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{mydescription}
\item[foo]  \label{foo} foo is good
\item[bar]  \label{bar} bar is bad
\end{mydescription}

For good things (see, for example \ref{foo})\dots

For bad things (see, for example \ref{bar})\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change what `\ref` will display for equations if you include the `amsmath` package and use the `\tag` command, like so:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
\begin{equation}\label{eq:energy}\tag{Einstein}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
...
Invoking the energy-mass equivalence of \ref{eq:energy}
```

I'm not aware of a straightforward method to accomplish it in general though, since if the tag you want is not going to be changed by edits or recompilations, there's no need to make TeX keep track of it.

I would accomplish what you are attempting by defining a new command to be the text of the description:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
....
\begin{description}
\item[\foo] foo is good
....
\end{description}
....
For good things (see, for example \foo)...
```

That way if you decide later that the description should instead be `bar`, you just have to change the one defining command to `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}` and all subsequent places that you use `\foo` will automatically get updated to display `bar`.

Comment: Your second idea is what I've been doing. I'd really prefer a solution that allows me to "link back" via the internal links in the PDF file. I've found out that the built-in "description" list environment is designed to be label-less. So I'd probably have to look at external packages for this.

Comment: Using the `hyperref` package it's possible to display something other than the label that's being referenced, for example `\hyperref[eq:fib]{Fibonacci Sequence}`.  For more details, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks

Comment: But if the <code>\label</code> object is referring to the wrong thing (the subsection, and not the list object), then hyperref will jump it to the wrong spot in the document. This would not be an acceptable work around. Again the problem seems to be that the built-in description list has no support for labels.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would not recommend using a description/enumeration/itemization for your task, but from the answer I will provide now, you could derive how to overwrite the `\item` macros/commands if you *really* want to use a description environment.

Here is what I would do:

```
\newcounter{foocnt}   %% define a counter
\setcounter{foocnt}{0} %% set the counter to some initial value (not really important)
%%%% Parameters
% #1: Title
\newenvironment{fooEnvironment}[1]
{
    \renewcommand{\thefoocnt}{\textbf{#1}}  %% this is where the display of the counter is overwritten/modified
    \refstepcounter{foocnt} %% increment counter (in this case we write the custom label/title to a temp. file which is read when the document resolves a \ref)
    \par  %% start new paragraph (this is just an example for format modifications)
    \textbf{#1:}  %% display the title before the content of the environment is displayed
}{
    \par  %% another paragraph after the environment
}
```

This solution can be used as follows to be equivalent to your example:

```
\begin{fooEnvironment}{foo}
foo is good
\label{fooLabel}
\end{fooEnvironment}
\begin{fooEnvironment}{bar}
bar is bad
\label{barLabel}
\end{fooEnvironment}
For good things (see, for example \ref{fooLabel})...
```

The lesson learned here is: At the definition of a counter with name `blubb` there is a macro defined called `\theblubb` which contains the string being printed in the document when the counter is referenced. Obviously, a solution where an additional parameter to the environment is provided to make the display of the reference different to the title is possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in links to arbitrary text, somewhere in the document, the following variations offers a solution, with custom text for the link, different than the label it point to:

```
\newcounter{desccount}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{desccount}\label{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\descref}[2][\undefined]{%
\ifx#1\undefined%
    \hyperref[#2]{#2}%
\else%
    \hyperref[#2]{#1}%
\fi%
}%
```

and in the text use:

```
\descitem{linklabel} text next to label, you will be directed here...

\newpage
\descref[after clicking on this optional text]{linklabel}
```

Comment: This seems to be answering my comments [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-does-one-set-custom-labels-for-description-lists/124641?noredirect=1#comment342_293). (For those who didn't read through the whole thread; incidentally this also means that the `hyperref` package is used for this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

to improve on [@Michael's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/293/241038) to allow for custom labels, you can use the following:

#### Separate label and description

```latex
\newcounter{desccount}

\newcommand{\descitem}[2]{%
  \item[#1] \refstepcounter{desccount}\label{#2}%
  % define a command of argument 2 (the label) that prints argument 1 (the descitem)
  \expandafter\xdef\csname#2\endcsname{#1}%
}

% use this command to hyperref
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\csname#1\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \descitem{Sweet options}{desc:sweetOptions}: Options that are sweet, such as sweets
  \descitem{Savoury options}{desc:savOptions}: Options that are Savoury, such as cheese.
\end{description}
I made a recipe using both \descref{desc:sweetOptions} and \descref{desc:savOptions}.

We can also invoke the created command:
Print the text associated with the label for \csname desc:sweetOptions\endcsname
\end{document}
```

#### How it works:

[`\expandafter\xdef\csname`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39412/241038) allows to (globally) define a command based on an argument. Thus, there will be a command named `\desc:sweetOptions`. Because commands cannot have `:`, we have to invoke it inside `\csname desc:sweetOpions\endcsname`. Furthermore, we have to use `\xdef` in stead of `\newcommand`, in order to [expand it, and be globally available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/662928/241038).