# What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?

Tags: macros, tex-core

What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do? What are their job?
I have glanced at the Texbook and some other books, but none of them was clear enough to me.
Can anyone please give a simple example to clarify this issue?

Comment: See [TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html), section 11.6

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Normally, control sequence names are made only of letters or of *one* non-letter character.

A letter is, more precisely, a character having category code 11 at the moment the control sequence name is read. So, any character can become part of a control sequence name, provided we change its catcode before the definition and each usage.

With `\csname...\endcsname` we are freed from this limitation and every character can go inside them to form a control sequence name (of course, `%` is excluded because it disappears together with what remains on the line before TeX is doing its work on characters).

However, this is not the main purpose of `\csname...\endcsname`. This construction is used to build commands from "variable parts". Think, for instance to LaTeX's `\newcounter`: after `\newcounter{foo}`, TeX knows `\thefoo` that is built precisely in this way. Roughly, what LaTeX does is

```
\newcommand{\newcounter}[1]{%
   \expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
   \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\arabic{#1}}%
 }
```

so that `\newcounter{foo}` does the right job. It's more complicated than this, of course, but the main things are here; `\newcount` is the low-level command to allocate a counter. The `\expandafter` is just to build the control sequence before `\newcount` and `\def` see the token.

Inside `\csname...\endcsname`, category codes don't matter (with one main exception: active characters *will* be expanded if not preceded by `\string`, see final note). LaTeX exploits this in order to build control sequence names that users won't be able to access (easily). For example, the control sequence to choose the default ten point font is `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10`, which can be easily split internally (by the "reverse" operation that is `\string`) and is not available to the casual user.

Another important use is in environments: when you say `\newenvironment{foo}`, LaTeX really defines `\foo` and `\endfoo`. Upon finding `\begin{foo}`, LaTeX does some bookkeeping and then executes `\csname foo\endcsname` (that's why one can say also `\newenvironment{foo*}`); similarly, at `\end{foo}` LaTeX executes `\csname endfoo\endcsname` and after this it does some bookkeeping again.

Other uses: `\label{foo}` will define control sequences based on `foo` via `\csname...\endcsname` that can be used by `\ref`.

When one says `\csname foo\endcsname`, LaTeX will look whether `\foo` is defined; if not, it will execute `\relax` and from then on (respecting grouping), `\foo` will be interpreted as `\relax`. An interesting usage for this feature is that one can say

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\csname phantomsection\endcsname
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

and keep `hyperref` happy if it's loaded, while doing nothing if the package is not loaded.

It's possible to give many other interesting uses of this trick. But one should always keep in mind that TeX does *complete expansion* of what it finds in that context and that *only characters* must remain. So

```
\csname abc\relax def\endcsname
```

is forbidden. But, after `\def\xyz{abc}`,

```
\csname \xyz def\endcsname
```

will be legal and equivalent to saying `\csname abcdef\endcsname` or `\abcdef`.

### Final note

It's better to add something about category codes. An active character in `\csname...\endcsname` will be expanded, so to get a literal `~` one has to write `\string~`. Comment (category 14), ignored (category 9) and invalid (category 15) characters will remain such. So

```
\csname %\endcsname
```

will give an error (Missing `\endcsname`); in `\csname ^^@\endcsname` there will be *no* character and `\csname ^^?\endcsname` will raise an error.

Comment: Braces don't need to be balanced. `\expandafter\show\csname{\endcsname` works fine with usual catcodes. Otherwise, very good response.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Right; they have to be balanced only if used to surround arguments to macros, of course.

Comment: I've written ```\expandafter\def\csname com?mand\endcsname{some text}```. Then I tried to use the ```\com?mand```: 
```\com?mand``` raises an error ```\com``` is undefined;
```{\catcode`\?=11 \com?mand}``` works; 
```\csname com?mand \endcsname``` does nothing. So what is the best way to use the \def'ed command?

Comment: @Vladimir You can't use `\com?mand` unless you change the category code of `?`; you also seem to have a space in front of `\endcsname` and it should be removed.

Comment: *"When one says `\csname foo\endcsname`, LaTeX will look whether `\foo` is defined; if not, it will execute `\relax` and from then on (**respecting grouping**), `\foo` will be interpreted as `\relax`."*  Perhaps it is worth emphasizing that respecting grouping = `\foo` being interpreted as `\relax` only within the scope where `\csname foo\endcsname` occurred is the case even if the integer-parameter `\globaldefs` has a positive value indicating that all assignments shall be global.

Comment: Perhaps it is also noteworthy that when doing something like `\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{bla}` it makes a difference whether this takes place inside/outside the definition-text of a macro: Outside macro-definitions you can use `\csname #1\endcsname` for defining/calling a macro whose name is `\#1`.Inside the definition-text of a macro hashes not denoting arguments of the macro need to be duplicated - `\csname ##1\endcsname` occurring inside a macro-definition yields a token `\#1` (`#1` is the literal name of the token, not a placeholder) at the time of expanding the macro in question.

Comment: The trick `\csname foo\endcsname` when foo is not defined doesn't seem to work in Overleaf giving me this error: _Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn’t compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log_ but I can't see anything related in log. I was going to ask about th error but then I tested the same construct in TexLive 2021 (Ubuntu), using lualatex and have got the expected result.

Comment: @Celdor Please, ask a follow-up question with the details.

Comment: I found it. Everything's working. I did not realise LaTeX would complain if  `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` was empty. It turned out local files had extra `X` besides the line with `\csname foo\endcsname`. When `\foo` wan't defined, Overleaf files ended up with empty `document` environment, which LaTeX complained about.

Comment: Notice that in LaTeX3, many usages of `\csname...\endcsname` have been advantageously replaced by `c` and `v` expansions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:cpn { ^^J } #1 % instead of \expandafter\def\csname ^^J \endcsname
  { Hello\space#1! }
\use:c { ^^J } { world } % instead of \csname ^^J \endcsname { world }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

See the interface3.pdf documentation for the more examples and `v` expansion.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS Better yet, we have `\UseName{c}{...}` and `\ExpandArgs{c}`.

Answer (score 40):

For reference, from the TeX Book (with slight formatting changes), **Chapter 7: How TeX Reads What You Type** (p 40):

> ...you can go from a list of character tokens to a control sequence by
>   saying `\csname<tokens>\endcsname`. The tokens that appear in this
>   construction between `\csname` and `\endcsname` may include other
>   control sequences, as long as those control sequences ultimately
>   expand into characters instead of TeX primitives; the final characters
>   can be of any category, not necessarily letters. For example, `\csname
>   TeX\endcsname` is essentially the same as `\TeX`; but
>   `\csname\TeX\endcsname` is illegal, because `\TeX` expands into tokens
>   containing the `\kern` primitive. Furthermore,
>   `\csname\string\TeX\endcsname` will produce the unusual control
>   sequence `\\TeX`, i.e., the token `<\TeX>`, which you can't ordinarily
>   write.

I have used this *indirectly* by using the `\label`-`\ref` system and defining labels based on counters:

```
\newcounter{mycount}
%...
\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
  \label{abc\themycount}%
  %...
}
```

This creates a "successive label `abc1`, `abc2`, ... for every call to `\mycmd`, in order to avoid creating multiply defined labels with the same name. Indirectly, `\label{abc\themycount}` calls `\@namedef{r@abc\themycount}`, which calls

```
\expandafter\def\csname r@abc\themycount\endcsname
```

thereby expanding `r@abc\themycount` to `r@abc1` and defining `\r@abc1` for the first label, `\r@abc2` for the second label, etc. Yes, labels in LaTeX are actually control sequences prepended with `r@` and is constructed using `\csname ... \endcsname` which then allows numerals.

Answer (score 28):

Suppose you want to define a command `\foo2`.  You cannot do this because 2 is not a letter.  However, this construction works: `\csname foo2\endcsname`.  Sometimes this is useful, e.g. when you need a series of commands, `\foo1`, `\foo2`, etc (another way is to use roman numerals).  Another example, suppose you want to define a series of commands like `\endsection`, `\endsubsection`, etc.  Then you can use a loop with `\expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname...`

Comment: Thanks for your example, but can you tell me what  generally their job are? When and where do I need to use them?

Comment: Well, @egreg beat me to it.  Basically a TeX command is either (1) a sequence of letters starting from `\`, e.g. `\parskip`, or (2) a special symbol optionally preceded by a backslash, e.g. `\@`, and (3) any sequence of symbols between `\csname` and `\endcsname`.  So the job of these commands is to introduce a way to produce TeX commands.  You do not need to use them unless you do TeX programming.  In the latter case they are handy.

Comment: sounds like double quotes in bash or perl

Answer (score 28):

`\csname`/`\endcsname` allows you to build commands whose names contains 1. non-letters (e.g. dots or colons or numbers) and - more importantly - 2. commands which are expanded when you define or use the command. Both is useful if you want to construct a command name from various pieces of informations.

As an example: The xskak-Package loops through the notation of a chess game and stores a lot of informations of every move in commands. Its code contains a lot of definition of this type:

```
\expandafter\xdef
     \csname Xskak.\xskak@val@gameid.\the\c@move.\WhiteToMove{w}{b}.piece\endcsname{%
      ....
      }
```

where `\xskak@val@gameid` is the id of the current game, `\the\c@move` gives the current move number, `\WhiteToMove{w}{b}` gives w or b depending on which player currently moves. So in the 10th move of black in the game with id "mygame" this `\xdef` defines a "command" `\Xskak.mygame.10.b.piece` which contains the name of the piece which has been moved by black in the tenth move.

Answer (score 23):

Short answer: `\csname` and `\endcsname` are a "macro environment" whose contents, if they evaluate (after expanding macros) to "ordinary text", are converted into the name of a macro (or *control sequence*, hence "csname").

---

Actually, it is a perhaps strange joke that by the rules of LaTeX macros, you can actually write `\begin{csname}...\end{csname}` and it will act as you expect, to a certain extent.  For example:

```
\def\macro{text}
\def\o{o}
\begin{csname}%
 macr\o
\end{csname}
% Same as \csname macr\o \endcsname
```

(when run with `latex` rather than `tex`) will produce the word "text" in the output.  The `%` sign is there so that unnecessary spaces don't creep into the name of the macro we are constructing.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do? What are their job?

**Short/oversimplified story:**

`\csname ... \endcsname` can be used for obtaining the control-sequence-token whose name is denoted by the tokens nested between `\csname` and `\endcsname`.

Expansion is not suppressed but is triggered with the tokens nested between `\csname` and `\endcsname`.

`\csname` itself is expandable.

So you can say:

Expanding the token `\csname` causes TeX to remove the token `\csname` and to initiate the process of gathering the name of a control-sequence-token by gathering explicit unexpandable character-tokens, hereby not suppressing but triggering expansion of expandable tokens.

A token `\endcsname` that matches a preceding token `\csname` is also removed and ends that process of gathering and triggers replacing the gathered explicit unexpandable
character-tokens by the corresponding control-sequence-token.

You can use macros for storing data by having macros expand to tokens, e.g., sequences of character-tokens, that represent data.
Assume you wish to systematize names of macro-tokens so that based on the names of the macro-tokens one can deduce what data are (to be) stored in them. Conversely, if you know the type of data, you wish to be able to deduce the names of the macro-tokens in which the data in question are (to be) stored.
In such situations you also need a mechanism for getting from the name of a macro-token to the macro-token itself. This is when `\csname..\endcsname` is handy.

**Complicated story:**

Basically `\csname` triggers TeX into expanding expandable tokens and keeping unexpandable explicit character-tokens until encountering

- either a matching `\endcsname`,
- or a non-expandable control-sequence-token.

In the further case the resulting set of unexpandable tokens consists only of unexpandable explicit character-tokens. That set of unexpandable explicit character-tokens is taken for the name of a control-sequence-token by which that set of unexpandable explicit character-tokens is replaced.

In the latter case an error-message about inserting a missing `\endcsname` is delivered and the missing `\endcsname`-token is inserted before the non-expandable control-sequence-token in question. Thus the unexpandable explicit character-tokens gathered so far are taken for the name of a control-sequence-token and the corresponding control-sequence-token is delivered.
That control-sequence-token in turn is trailed by the non-expandable control-sequence-token that triggered the error-message about inserting a missing `\endcsname`.

In case expansion during the process of gathering initiated by `\csname` triggers an error-message, e.g., due to a control-sequence being undefined, or due to the use of a macro not matching its definition, TeX will ignore the tokens causing the error-message.

Some examples of `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions:

```tex
\csname TeX\endcsname
```

yields the control-sequence-token `\TeX`.

```tex
\csname Te\relax\endcsname
```

yields

- an error-message about inserting a missing `\endcsname` and
- insertion of `\endcsname` before `\relax` because `\relax` is a non-expandable control-sequence-token.

Thus this—except for the error-message about inserting a missing `\endcsname`—is like
`\csname Te\endcsname\relax\endcsname`
, i.e., you get the control-sequence token `\Te`, trailed by `\relax`, trailed by `\endcsname`, whereby `\endcsname` may trigger an error-message about extra-`\endcsname`.

Inside `\edef`/`\xdef` and the like you don't get extra-`\endcsname`-errors:
E.g., `\edef\macro{a\endcsname}` doesn't trigger error-messages and yields that `\macro` expands to the tokens `a\endcsname`.

```tex
\def\macro{Te}
\csname\macro X\endcsname
```

yields the control-sequence-token `\TeX`: `\csname` is removed and triggers gathering explicit unexpandable character-tokens that represent the name of a control-sequence-token, whereby expansion of expandable tokens is not suppressed but triggered. Thus `\macro` is expanded and yields `Te`. Then `X` is found. Then the matching `\endcsname` is found. The matching `\endcsname` is removed and triggers replacing the characters `TeX` that were found so far by the control-sequence-token whose name is `TeX`, i.e., by the control-sequence-token `\TeX`. I.e., the character-tokens `T`, `e`, `x` are removed and the control-sequence-token `\TeX` is inserted.

```tex
\csname a\undefined b\endcsname
```

yields

- an error-message about `\undefined` being undefined and
- the control-sequence-token `\ab`.

```tex
\def\delimited x{y}
\csname ab\delimited z\endcsname
```

yields

- an error-message about `\delimited` not matching its definition and
- the control-sequence-token `\ab`.

```tex
\def\macroA{Te}
\def\macroB{X}
\csname\csname macroA\endcsname\csname macroB\endcsname\endcsname
```

yields the control-sequence-token `\TeX`: `\csname` both triggers expansion and itself is expandable and therefore `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions can be nested (as long as sufficient memory is available/as long as TeX-capacities are not exceeded by having too many pending `\csname..`-thingies).

```tex
\csname TeX\csname endcsname\endcsname
```

seems a little imbalanced at first glimpse but yields the control-sequence-token `\TeX`.

---

If a control-sequence-token delivered by `\csname..\endcsname` is undefined, it will be assigned the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive (only!) within the scope where the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression occurred. (This is the case even if the `\globaldefs`-parameter has a positive value.)

---

Basic facts/tricks related to expansion:

First:

`\csname` itself is expandable: The tokens forming the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression are removed from the token-stream. The replacement is the control-sequence-token whose name is denoted by the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression. In expansion-contexts where you wish to control the order in time in which single expansion-steps take place, triggering one expansion-step on `\csname` is sufficient for obtaining that token.

Second:

Expansion is not suppressed with the tokens forming the "content" of a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression.

Thus:

With subsequent `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions you can have `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions further ahead trigger carrying out `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions further back—e.g., triggering expansion of the first `\csname` in

```
\csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\csname bar\expandafter\endcsname\csname baz\endcsname
```

yields

`\foo\bar\baz`.

The token `\expandafter` right before the first `\csname..\endcsname`-expression's `\endcsname` triggers TeX into producing the expansion-result of the second `\csname` before "looking" at the first `\endcsname`.

The token `\expandafter` right before the second `\csname..\endcsname`-expression's `\endcsname` triggers TeX into producing the expansion-result of the third `\csname` before "looking" at the second `\endcsname`.

In other words:

Due to `\expandafter` occurring right before the first `\csname..\endcsname`-expression's `\endcsname` the second `\csname..\endcsname`-expression is evaluated while evaluation of the first `\csname..\endcsname`-expression is still in progress.

Due to `\expandafter` occurring right before the second `\csname..\endcsname`-expression's `\endcsname` the third `\csname..\endcsname`-expression in turn is evaluated while evaluation of the second `\csname..\endcsname`-expression is still in progress.