# ConTeXt: How do you create your own commands?

Tags: context, programming

There seems to be a Current and Standard way to define new (core) commands in ConTeXt. For example, [an e-mail by Wolfgang](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2012/065888.html) states:

> Many of the \define... and \setup... commands are now auto generated 
>    from \installcommandhandler which generates only one setup-command 
>    which can be used for global (i.e. \setup…[..,..=..,..]) and local 
>    (i.e. \setup...[...][..,..=..,..]) settings. For backward compatibility you 
>    can find things like this: \let\setupnotes\setupnote

I cannot wrap my head around the source code, and I cannot find any documentation on the commands involved.

For example, the code that creates `\startnarrower` and `\setupnarrower`, from [spac-hor.mkiv](http://standalone.contextgarden.net/current/context/alpha/tex/context/base/spac-hor.mkiv):

```
\installcorenamespace{narrower}
\installcorenamespace{narrowermethod}

% ... (some code skipped)
\installcommandhandler \??narrower {narrower} \??narrower

\appendtoks
   %% this means: \def\startmynarrower{\spac_narrower_start{mynarrower}}
   \setuevalue{\e!start\currentnarrower}{\spac_narrower_start%
     {\currentnarrower}}%
   %% this means: \def\startmynarrower{\spac_narrower_stop}
   \setuevalue{\e!stop \currentnarrower}{\spac_narrower_stop}%
\to \everydefinenarrower

% \??narrowermethod is the narrowermethod corenamespace?
\unexpanded\def\installnarrowermethod#1#2%
  {\setvalue{\??narrowermethod#1}{#2}}

% ...

\installnarrowermethod \v!left  {\global\advance\s_spac_narrower_left%
    \narrowerparameter\c!left  \relax}
\installnarrowermethod \v!middle{\global\advance\s_spac_narrower_mid%
    \narrowerparameter\c!middle\relax}
```

So, what do these commands do/mean?

- `\installcorenamespace`
- `\??...`
- `\installcommandhandler`, and possibly its buddies defined in [mult-aux.mkiv](http://standalone.contextgarden.net/current/context/alpha/tex/context/base/mult-aux.mkiv) and elsewhere: `\installswitchcommandhandler`, `\installautocommandhandler`, 
  `\installsimplecommandhandler`, `\installframedautocommandhandler`, etc.
- `\setuevalue`

Comment: Wrt. namespaces you might want to have a look at [mult-aux.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/mult-aux.mkiv): `installcorenamespace` is reserved for Hans, use `installnamespace` or `definenamespace` instead. There’s also a [section on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Module_Namespaces#Generating_a_Namespace_for_Your_Module) dedicated to module namespacing. Also look at [syst-aux.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/syst-aux.mkiv) for the constants `\c!...`, `\v!...`.

Comment: Thank you for those links. By the way, I am equally interested in deciphering existing command definitions as in writing my own, so e.g. `\installcorenamespace` is also interesting even though I can't use it; especially because it is not user-facing and therefore less documented.

Comment: Small self-answer: `\csname...\endcsname` expands its contents, sticks a backslash in front, and TeX then pretends that that was what you wrote. See [this SE answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39382/2229). It's used inside `\setuevalue`, for example, to piece together `\e!start\currentnarrower` into `\startnarrower`, or `\startmynarrower`, or `\demarrecompoetroite".

Comment: See, especially, the *TeXbook*, page 40.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Creating a name space

To create a namespace the command `\installnamespace` is used in contrast to
`\installcorenamespace`, which is reserved for command in the core. They
basically do the same. `\installnamespace{whatever}` creates a new control
sequence `\????whatever`, which expands to something random, say `345>`. The
command `\installcorenamespace` creates a command with just two question
marks. You never need this value, since it's only accessed via the control
sequence.

### Creating a command handler

The command `\installcommandhandler` is called like this:

```
\installcommandhandler \????whatever {whatever} \????whatever
```

It creates several commands that are used in ConTeXts user interface:

```
\definewhatever [myA]
\setupwhatever  [key=value]
\setupwhatever  [myA] [key=value]
```

It creates bunch of other command handlers as well, like the `\everydefine…` token lists.

Also an interesting read: The higher level command `\definenamespace` (see
[Module Namespaces](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Module_Namespaces)):

### Access to the values

After

```
\installcommandhandler \????whatever {whatever} \????whatever
```

and

```
\setupwhatever  [foo=globalbar]
\definewhatever [mywhatever]
\setupwhatever  [mywhatever] [key=value, foo=localbar]
```

the values can be accessed by

```
\whateverparameter{foo}                  % ⇒ globalbar (*not* localbar!)
\namedwhateverparameter{mywhatever}{key} % ⇒ value
\namedwhateverparameter{mywhatever}{foo} % ⇒ globalbar (inherits from \setupwhatever)
```

after `\def\currentwhatever{mywhatever}`

```
\whateverparameter{foo} % ⇒ localbar
```

### Altering the values

With `\set…parameter{key}{value}` one can change or set values. If `\current…` is
empty, then the global key is changed, if `\current…` is set, then the change
applies locally.

```
\installnamespace{whatever}
\installcommandhandler \????whatever {whatever} \????whatever

\setupwhatever  [foo=globalbar]
\definewhatever [mywhatever]
\setupwhatever  [mywhatever] [key=value, foo=localbar]

\setwhateverparameter{foo}{newvalueglobal} % alters global foo
\whateverparameter{foo}

\def\currentwhatever{mywhatever}
\setwhateverparameter{foo}{newvaluelocal} % alters local foo

\whateverparameter{foo} % local foo changed

\let\currentwhatever\empty
\whateverparameter{foo} % global foo unchanged
```

### Conventions

The following information is taken from the [Context wiki - System
Macros](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Scratch_Variables)

```
\s!: These are macros holding system constants, ie. values that never change
\c!: These are macros holding constant keys in key-value pairs.
     The actual definitions depend on the multi-lingual interface that is
     currently being used.
\v!: These are macros holding names of variable values in key-value pairs.
     The actual definitions depend on the multi-lingual interface that is
     currently being used.
\??: These are multi-lingual interface constant calls.
\@@: These are results of a multi-lingual interface constant expansion.
```

`\setuevalue` is defined as follows

```
\def\setuevalue#1{\normalprotected\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
```

So it basically acts as an `\edef`.

Comment: Further to what `\setuevalue` does: I've worked out what the `ue` means. Looking at [the source](http://standalone.contextgarden.net/current/context/alpha/tex/context/base/syst-aux.mkiv), the `\set*value` commands are for assignments using `\csname`, which is the multilingual-friendly technique; the `e` stands for `\edef`; and the `u` macros all have `\normalprotected`, so I think it stands for 'user(-facing)'.

Comment: `\csname` has nothing to do with the multilingual interface. It enables passing an arbitrary string, which would fail otherwise due to catcode issues. Eg. `\setvalue{3&_}{foo}` and `\getvalue{3&_}`

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was unclear: I meant "assigning things using \csname" is a multilingual-friendly technique, because instead of mentioning the command you're defining you can use `\csname` to piece it together from language-independent placeholders. E.g. `\expandafter\def\csname\e!start\currentnarrower\endcsname{...}` is flexible, while `\def\demarreMonNarrower` is set in stone. ---- On top of the useful ability to paste comes the  useful property of catcode-independence, as you say.