# Dagger symbol in math mode in ConTeXt with Euler font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, context, context-mkiv

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149688/5919) to use the Neo Euler font in math mode.  I found that the dagger symbol (†) is missing in Euler.  Is there a way to use the dagger symbol from the text mode font in math mode?

Here’s a minimal example:

```
\usetypescriptfile[euler]
\definetypeface[mainface][rm][serif][palatino]       [default]
\definetypeface[mainface][ss][sans] [helvetica]        [default] [rscale=auto]
\definetypeface[mainface][mm][math] [pagellaovereuler] [default] [rscale=auto]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]
\appendtoks \rm \to \everymathematics
\setupmathematics
  [lcgreek=normal, ucgreek=normal, integral=nolimits]

\starttext
Dagger in text mode: †

Math mode: $†$ ${\rm †}$        % Both don’t work.
\stoptext
```

And rendered result:

[image: Result]

My ConTeXt version is “current version: 2015.04.15 01:44”.
What I want is to at least make `${\rm †}$` work.

---

UPDATE: In comment, @Thruston mentioned that `$\hbox{†}$` works.  The problem is then I only use dagger for superscript, and `$x^{\hbox{†}}$` will not shrink the size of dagger like usual superscript would do.  So for now my workaround is

```
\define\dagger{\hbox{\tfx †}}
```

I’ve used `\dagger` instead of the unicode character in all my previous documents, so this would work (at least in documents without nestied superscripts involving daggers) if I ever want to recompile my existing documents.

---

UPDATE2: Well…

Turns out I can just `$x^{\text{†}}$`, not sure how I managed to forget that.

Comment: Is `$\hbox{†}$` acceptable?  Seems to work at my end.

Comment: @Thruston: It works!  Thank you.  But there’s a problem: If I type something like `$x^{\hbox{†}}$`, the dagger won’t shrink as a normal superscript would.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I can't do lua, and I must be going at the moment, but I'm thinking some sort of lua equivalent to the following: `\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\sdagger{\ThisStyle{\scalerel*{\hbox{$\SavedStyle \dagger$}}{f}}}`

Comment: Well in Latex you need to set that character up as a maths character but I'm not sure of the equivalent in Context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the fallback for dagger:

```
\unprotect
\definefontfallback [pagellaovereuler] [texgyrepagella-math] [0x02020]         [\c!check=\v!yes,\c!force=\v!yes]
\protect
```

Full working example:

```
\usetypescriptfile[euler]
\definetypeface[mainface][rm][serif][palatino]       [default]
\definetypeface[mainface][ss][sans] [helvetica]        [default] [rscale=auto]
\definetypeface[mainface][mm][math] [pagellaovereuler] [default] [rscale=auto]

\unprotect
\definefontfallback [pagellaovereuler] [texgyrepagella-math] [0x02020]         [\c!check=\v!yes,\c!force=\v!yes]
\protect

\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]
\appendtoks \rm \to \everymathematics
\setupmathematics
  [lcgreek=normal, ucgreek=normal, integral=nolimits]

\starttext
Dagger in text mode: †

Math mode: $†$ ${\rm †}$        % Both work.
\stoptext
```

It may be a good idea to create the list of all other text symbols that are used in math mode and are missing in Euler, and then send it to the ConTeXt mailing list. That way, the fallbacks can be added to type-imp-euler.mkiv.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer: `$x^{\text{†}}$`. :-/