# Combining font switches in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context

I would like a set of macros to switch the font alternative in ConTeXt, to either italics, slanted, or bold, and I would like them to combine in an intuitive manner, similarly to LaTeX's `\textit` and `\textbf`.

The ConTeXt wiki says that the commands `\typeface`, `\boldface`, and `\swapface` behave similarly to how I want my macros to behave. Unfortunately, `\boldface` does not always preserve italics or slant, and there are no analogous commands for italics and slanted font alternatives. The following image, from [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching#Emphasizing_text), demonstrates the behavior of the mentioned commands for various current font alternatives.

[image: demonstration of commands]
<sub>(source: [contextgarden.net](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/wikiteximage/4bc3b592f8ad6e48e56940ad850fcb37.png))</sub>

After looking at the ConTeXt source code for `\typeface`, `\boldface`, and `\swapface`, found [here](https://repo.or.cz/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/font-emp.mkvi#l60), I tried creating my desired macros with the following code:

```
\unexpanded\def\normalItalic
    {\relax
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bf \bi \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bi \bi \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bs \bi \else
                                  \it \fi\fi\fi}
\unexpanded\def\normalSlanted
    {\relax
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bf \bs \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bi \bs \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bs \bs \else
                                  \sl \fi\fi\fi}
\unexpanded\def\normalBold
    {\relax
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!it \bi \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!sl \bs \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bi \bi \else
        \ifx\fontalternative\s!bs \bs \else
                                  \bf \fi\fi\fi\fi}
\def\Italic#1{{\normalItalic #1}}
\def\Slanted#1{{\normalSlanted #1}}
\def\Bold#1{{\normalBold #1}}
```

Unfortunately, these do not combine as I would expect, based on the behavior of `\typeface`, `\boldface`, and `\swapface`. `\Italic{Hello \Bold{World}!}` produces the output *Hello* **World***!* instead of the expected *Hello **World**!*

What causes my code to behave differently from the macros `\typeface`, `\boldface`, and `\swapface` so that they do not combine correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Inside_ConTeXt#Special_characters_in_command_names) on the ConTeXt wiki, some characters `@`, `!`, and `?` are not normally considered letters for the purpose of commands. In order to use these characters in a command, it must be surrounded by `\unprotect` and `\protect`.

It appears that `\s!bf` and similar commands are defined to be what can be returned by the macro `\fontalternative`, so they are better to use than just `bf` or similar in case `\fontalternative` is ever changed. Since macros like `\s!bf` need to be used in the attempted solution, `\unprotect` must be placed before the first definition, and `\protect` must be placed after the last definition. Without `\unprotect`, it seems `\s!bf` is interpreted as `\s! bf` so the `\ifx` ladder always follows the `\else` path.

With `\unprotect` and `\protect` added, `\Italic{Hello \Bold{World}!}` produces the expected output: *Hello **World**!*

Comment: Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110131/323 for another reason for using `\s!` etc.