# What does "\!" aka backslash exclamation mark do?

Tags: tables

I just came across this ! (backslash exclamation mark) in the code for a table in somebody else's tex and I was wondering what it does.

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
                \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
                \begin{tabular}{l | c c c | c r}
                        \toprule
                        \textbf{Thing} & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$\\
                        \midrule
                        Stuff &  \!\!100\!\!  &  \!\!$10^{6}$\!\! & \!\!$\pi_0$\!\! & $\sigma$ & $2^{30}$\\
                        \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}%
        }
\end{table}
```

My tex editor says unrecognized command but it compiles just fine.
I've tried on [overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/20875793smgbwfrkksnz#/) and it seems to tighten the table somehow. Does anybody know more?

Comment: A `\!` is a negative space, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-the-spacing-command for more information.

Comment: It *doesn't* compile fine!

Comment: @egreg I'm not getting any errors for the overleaf example. What do you mean?

Comment: @Elias I get 11 errors, after adding a suitable minimal preamble.

Comment: Hm..strange. Compiling the overleaf example with pdflatex I don't get any.

Comment: Let $x \in I\!\!R$.

[I have seen this in actual documents. Disclaimer: don't do this. Seriously.]

Comment: In ConTeXt it has another meaning, see [fonts - What does \s! do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/what-does-s-do/109896#109896)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know what the commands `\!` are supposed to do in the code you show, other than raising *many* errors.

The command `\!` is only allowed in math mode (unless redefined, which I'd discourage). It's purpose is to insert a *negative thin space*, which is useful in several places. For instance

```
\biggl(\frac{121}{12}-1\biggr)^{\!2}
```

is an improvement over `^{2}`, because it moves the exponent towards the parenthesis and takes care of its bending.

Another place where it is helpful is in `2/\!\log x`, because for technical reasons `/` is an ordinary symbol and TeX would add a thin space between it and the “log” operator.

Here's a picture: left the output with `\!`, right without.

[image]

The negative spacing of `\!` exactly matches the positive one by `\,` (which is automatically inserted in some places) in math mode. Note that `\,` can be used outside of math mode, where it inserts a sixth of a quad of space.

If you want to tighten a table, reduce the size of `\tabcolsep`. Using explicit negative spaces all over the place is not the correct way.

And ***never*** use `\resizebox` on a table.

Comment: Huh...I always thought this kind of stuff was automatic in tex. I have to fix such spaces manually?

Comment: @Elias There are more things in heaven and math formulas than are dreamt of by your TeX engine.

Comment: In any case, good to know, although I have no intention of fiddling with this kind of thing. :)

Answer (score 4):

This symbol is usually defined as

```
 \! negative thin space (normally 1/6 of a quad)
```

It is commonly used in tables, and formulas among other ways to manipulate spaces in LaTeX

And before you do post a question, please do run a [search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-the-spacing-command) with similar keywords on this site. Hope this helps.

Comment: Commonly used in tables? Please explain. I hardly never see it used other than in a few math constructions.

Comment: @daleif I am not sure if I can provide examples that are relevant here,  since it is a matter of usage, and remember coming across it in tables.

Comment: @GermanShepherd I tried searching for it but got no useful results. The search can't handle the special symbols, I guess. I didn't know it was called a negative thin space. ;)

Comment: @daleif Well, it can be used also for more bizarre goals as  [draw a donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312314/11604) `:-)`

Comment: @Fran That was a good one :-)