# ConTeXt and Metafun: Using environment variables inside overlay

Tags: context, framed, metafun

I would like to draw a custom frame for the `framed` environment using Metafun. I am currently hard-coding the frame color within the Metafun definition. However, I would like the Metafun frame to reference the `framecolor` option of the `framed` environment and change color accordingly. This is what I have so far with hard-coded color options:

```
\startuniqueMPgraphic{box}
path p;
p := unitcircle xscaled \overlaywidth yscaled \overlayheight;

fill p withcolor .85white;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor .625red;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[box][\uniqueMPgraphic{box}]

\starttext

\framed[framecolor=blue, background=box]{test}

\stoptext
```

Does the Metafun definition have access to `framed` options or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\framedparameter{framecolor}` to access the parameter. This results in an error if framecolor is not set. You can use `\MPcolor` with `\framedparameter` to fix that. Example:

```
\startuniqueMPgraphic{box}
  path p;
  p := unitcircle xscaled \overlaywidth yscaled \overlayheight;

  fill p withcolor .85white;
  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor \MPcolor{\framedparameter{framecolor}};
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [box]
  [\uniqueMPgraphic{box}]

\starttext
  \framed[framecolor=blue, background=box]{test}
  \framed[background=box]{foobar}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! To get a better understanding of the solution, is the `\[environment]parameter` type command general? Could I use something similar in contexts outside of just `framed`?

Comment: Yes, it's a general command. Also see [ConTeXt: How do you create your own commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/context-how-do-you-create-your-own-commands/58659#58659) This doesn't mean it works for *every* command. Only the ones that actually use the mentioned mechanisms.

Comment: @Marco You can also use the `OverlayLineColor` variable to access the `framecolor` value. This variable and many others are listed in the MetaFun manual.