# How can I combine two text strings to represent the name of a command?

Tags: macros, strings

I want to combine one command with a text string to represent a second command. In MatLab it would be possible to concatenate these two strings into one string and evaluate this new string. However I have no clue as to how this can be done in LaTeX. See my  working example below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}    
    \begin{document}


        \newcommand{\CaseID}{CaseOne} 

        \newcommand{\ProbabilityCaseOne}{1.00E-04}

        \paragraph{The results for \CaseID}

        \CaseID has probabilty  \Probability\CaseID


    \end{document}
```

The combination `\Probability\CaseID` does not work as a synonym for `\ProbabilityCaseOne`. How can I achieve a functionality like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can also be achieved in LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\CaseID}{CaseOne}

\newcommand{\ProbabilityCaseOne}{1.00E-04}

\paragraph{The results for \CaseID}

\CaseID{} has probabilty  \csname Probability\CaseID\endcsname

\paragraph{The results for \CaseID}

\makeatletter
\CaseID{} has probabilty  \@nameuse{Probability\CaseID}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

You can either use `\csname ... \endcsname` to construct a control sequence, or use `\@nameuse{...}`. The latter, of course, requires to be placed with the appropriate `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` scope. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) For the former, see the reference question [What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/5764)

A reference from the [TeX Book](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) (Chapter **7 How TeX Reads What You Type**, p 40):

> ... you can go from a list of character tokens to a
>   control sequence by saying `\csname\<tokens>\endcsname`. The tokens
>   that appear in this construction between `\csname` and `\endcsname` may
>   include other control sequences, as long as those control sequences
>   ultimately expand into characters instead of TeX primitives; the final
>   characters can be of any category, not necessarily letters. For example,
>   `\csname TeX\endcsname` is essentially the same as `\TeX`; but
>   `\csname\TeX\endcsname` is illegal, because `\TeX` expands into tokens
>   containing the `\kern` primitive. Furthermore,
>   `\csname\string\TeX\endcsname` will produce the unusual control sequence
>   `\\TeX` ...

---

The above all use the provided kernel functionality. However, [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) as a package provides similar constructions as wrappers for `\@nameuse` (and `\@namedef`). See section **3.1.1 Macro Deﬁnitions** (p 5) of the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf). In particular it provides `\csuse{...}`.

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds. :)

Answer (score 6):

Define a command that does the concatenation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}    
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\CaseID}{CaseOne} 
\newcommand{\ProbabilityCaseOne}{1.00E-04}

\newcommand{\Probability}[1]{\csname Probability#1\endcsname}

\section{The results for \CaseID}

\CaseID\ has probabilty  \Probability\CaseID

\end{document}
```

However, you can do in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefineCase}[3]{%
  % #1 is an identifier
  % #2 is the text
  % #3 is the probability
  \@namedef{ID@#1}{{#2}{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\CaseID}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo\csname ID@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\Probability}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo\csname ID@#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\DefineCase{1}{CaseOne}{1.00E-04}

\begin{document}
\section{The results for \CaseID{1}}

\CaseID{1} has probability \Probability{1}
\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\DefineCase` is an arbitrary string that identifies the case; the second is the corresponding text and the third is the associated probability. In this way you can define as many cases as you want, with a uniform syntax, for instance

```
\DefineCase{xyz}{Anything}{1}
```

will allow you to say in the document `\CaseID{xyz}` to print "Anything" and `\Probability{xyz}` to print 1.

[image]