# Concatenate two strings to make a new command

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, equations

I took some habits with my sciences reports so I developed some personalized commands.

First, I define in the preamble all the variables that I need like this:

```
\newcommand{\cvba}{Cv_{\beta/\alpha}}
\newcommand{\za}{z_{\alpha}}
...
```

Then I begin all my equation labels by "eq:" like in this example :

```
\begin{equation}
  \za = \frac{1000.-T}{34}
  \label{eq:za}
\end{equation}
```

And finally, I set a command which allows me to make a reference from a variable to its definition inside the environment equation :

```
\newcommand{\eref}[2]{\hyperref[eq:#1]{#2}}
```

In this example, `za` will point to the previous equation :

```
\begin{equation}
  \cvba = \eref{za}{\za}+12
  \label{eq:cvba}
\end{equation}
```

My problem is that I would like to make my new command `eref` a little bit easier and lighter to use such as it takes only one parameter.

I tried to define it like this :

```
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{\hyperref[eq:#1]{\#1}}
```

Obviously it doesn't work because the `\#` is understood as a specific character.

So my question is : "How could I concatenate two strings to make a new command?"

If it can helps, the names of my variables can change, for example they could be `\var_varname` such as he new command would looks like :

```
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{\hyperref[eq:#1]{\var_#1}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

instead of

```
\var_#1
```

you want

```
\csname var_#1\endcsname
```

Comment: It worked perfectly (without the underscore in the variable name)! Thanks.

Comment: For the ones who are interested, here is the good command : `\newcommand{\eref}[1]{\hyperref[eq:#1]{\csname #1\endcsname}}`

Comment: It is worth linking to egreg's luminous explanation of how `\csname` is 'is used to build commands from "variable parts"', so I shall: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39382/175

Comment: @CharlesStewart What? egreg has an answer more wordy than mine? I'm shocked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I'm sure you can draft a dreadnought-class answer to that question :)