# Using \csname in \renewcommand to change command definitions

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I'm trying to write a macro to change the definitions of \thesection, \thechapter, and other commands for the sectioning prefixes. I want to redefine only one of the commands depending on the user's input to a command. I've tried something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\changeprefix}[2]{
  %\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{#2} % ! Extra \endcsname.

  %\renewcommand \the#1{#2} %! Argument of \rem@pt has an extra }.

  %\def\headername{\csuse{the#1}}
  %\renewcommand \headername {#2} % compiles but has no effect

  %\renewcommand \csuse{the#1} {#2} % compiles but prints the value of #2

  \makeatletter
  \expandafter\renewcommand \@nameuse{the#1} {#2} % compiles but prints everything after \@
  \makeatother
}

\begin{document}
\changeprefix{section}{test prefix - }
\section{Test section}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

My attempts don't quite work. For the two bottom ones (that actually compile) I get the following output:

[image: No visual change]

[image: Prints value of #2 and some scrap text]

[image: Prints everything from the \@]

I've taken my inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124683/128253) as well as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117454/128253), but I'm not quite there yet. Is it possible to make this work and get the following output for the `\section{Test section}` call?

> test prefix - Test section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## First attempt

```
\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{#2}
```

You're trying to redefine `\csname` to be `t`

## Second attempt

```
\renewcommand \the#1{#2}
```

You're trying to redefine `\the` to expand to the first token in `#1`

## Third attempt

```
\def\headername{\csuse{the#1}}
\renewcommand \headername {#2} % compiles but has no effect
```

You're redefining `\headername`

## Fourth attempt

```
\renewcommand \csuse{the#1} {#2}
```

You're redefining `\csuse`

## Fifth attempt

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\renewcommand \@nameuse{the#1} {#2}
\makeatother
```

You're trying to define `\spacefactor`, because you're expanding `\@`. Note that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should surround the outer `\newcommand`, not be inside the replacement text. But this wouldn't fix the code, because

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\changeprefix[2]{
  \expandafter\renewcommand \@nameuse{the#1} {#2}
}
\makeatother
```

would try and redefine `\csname`, which is the first token in the expansion of `\@nameuse`.

## Correct version

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changeprefix}[2]{%
  \@namedef{the#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\newcommand{\changeprefix}[2]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This makes me realize there is a lot for me to learn regarding how LaTeX evaluates code.

Answer (score 5):

Since `etoolbox` is loaded already, there is a quicker way with `\csdef` or `\csgdef`, depending on the desired 'sustainability' in a group:

No 'weird' `\makeatletter...\expandafter...\makeatother` constructs to be used here:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\changeprefix}[2]{%
  \csdef{the#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\changeprefix{section}{test prefix - }
\section{Test section}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some additional experimenting I managed to get it working with a modification to the first attempt in the question so:

```
\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{#2}
```

became:

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{#2}
```

If I've understood this correctly, the `\renewcommand` macro was expanded before its input was finished. With this change the evaluation of `\renewcommand` is halted until `\csname ... \endcsname` has been evaluated.

I still don't quite know what was wrong with the other attempts, any input on these is welcome. But my problem is solved for now.

Comment: `\renewcommand\csname t` is `\renewcommand\csname{t}` and redefines `\csname` to be `t` after that latex is pretty broken and you will get assorted errors.

Comment: Not quite, what happens is that the \csname macro is expanded by \expandafter, and \renewcommand is applied to the resulting string.