# Wrap text to quote it later in the same document

Tags: environments

I was wondering if there's a way to do the following:

- to wrap an excerpt of text in an environment and to label it;
- to quote it (entirely) later in the same document, via a `\ref` command or similar.

By doing so, one could modify the wrapped text, without having to update all of the later references to it in the document.

I'm aware that a simple workaround would be to use `\input{}` both in the first and in the later occurrences of the wrapped sentence; I only wanted to know if there's  something more specific.

More in detail, my purpose is to wrap some text that I have to cite in an answer letter to the reviewer of a submitted paper.

Suppose I wrote in a first version of the paper that:

```
it is clear that 2+2=5
```

Now the reviewer makes me pay attention to the fact that there's an error. I correct it and:

1 - in the revised version of the paper I write:

```
\wraptext{twoplustwo}{it is clear that 2+2=4}
```

provided that `\wraptext{}{}` is the command I was looking for;

2 - in the answer to the reviewer, I specify:

> the error has been corrected, as you can see in the following reported excerpt:

```
\citewrappedtext{twoplustwo}
```

again provided that `\citewrappedtext{}` is the command to recall the excerpt.

This way, one can later modify again the sentence:

```
\wraptext{twoplustwo}{it is obvious that 2+2=4}
```

without having to correct the quotes, too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Could you give an example of how you'd like to use it?  (I would check out `\savebox`.)

Comment: A simple way is to use `\newcommand`; can you show some short examples of what you want?

Comment: I think OP asked for an environment, but a `\newcommand` would definitely get the job done.  Couldn't manage to express `\newcommand` as an environment though, even with packages like `environ`.

Comment: @SeanAllred You probably missed to put `\expandafter` here and there at random. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Ha! I've more-or-less given up on learning the effective control of expansion.  For this, I was [trying to use `expl3`](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/7031558) for practice.

Comment: @SeanAllred The `\expandafter\endcsname` trick is really nice.

Comment: Hi to all of you,
I didn't look at tex.stackexchange for a few days and realize only know that you've been answering to my question - at least now it is clear that it was not that urgent :) .
Anyway, the least I could do to thank you was to add more details to my question as you asked me to.
I'm going to try your suggestions and let you know.
Thank you very much once more :)

Answer (score 7):

While the answers "use a command" or "use an environment" seem to be obvious, here's a solution "with batteries included" ([@GitHub](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/quotedtext), [ZIP archive](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/archive/quotedtext.zip)):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\declquotedtext[2]{\expandafter\def\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\defquotedtext[2]{\declquotedtext{#1}{#2}#2}
\newcommand\usequotedtext[1]{\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname}

\begin{document}
  \defquotedtext{test}{This is a test text.}

  \declquotedtext{later}{And this is a text declared for later use.}

  This is something completely unrelated.

  \usequotedtext{test}

  \usequotedtext{later}
\end{document}
```

The command `\defquotedtext` will accept a label and contents, define the label (for use in `\usequotedtext`) *and* print the contents (to avoid repetition). As suggested by Ruben, `\declquotedtext` will do what `\defquotedtext` does, *without* printing the contents:

[image: Result of compilation]

As usual with commands, be careful with spaces after `\defquotedtext` and `\usequotedtext`.

Actually, I assumed that this has been packaged somewhere...

With credits to: [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/8057)

Comment: An option that makes it possible to only store a citation and make it reusable later would be nice too, i guess. (Or better: I can imagine some sitautions in which it could be helpful.)

Comment: @Ruben: See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Doing this with an environment is quite easy, by using `environ`.

The actual implementation depends on what you really have in mind. What I propose can even go in a secondary file that's `\input` at `\begin{document}`. The order of the text snippets is unimportant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{storequote}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{storequote@\detokenize{#1}}
    {\global\expandafter
     \def\csname storequote@\detokenize{#1}\expandafter\endcsname
     \expandafter{\BODY}}
    {\@latex@error{storequote error: key `\detokenize{#1}' already used}{\@ehd}}%
}
\newcommand{\getstoredquote}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{storequote@\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{storequote}{funny}
This is a funny quotation.
\end{storequote}

\begin{storequote}{bad}
This is a bad quotation.
\end{storequote}

\begin{storequote}{funny}
This will raise an error.
\end{storequote}

Some text just to call ``\getstoredquote{bad}'' and
some other text for calling ``\getstoredquote{funny}''.
Enough.

\end{document}
```

[image]