# What is the command \csname used for?

Tags: programming

Maybe a stupid question...but I often see the usage of `\csname` in code -- especially in packages. Can someone explain what its purpose is?

As far as I see it generates a new command based on an argument.

Comment: This is not a standard command... for the manuals of my packages I have a definition of `\cs` that prints the command name (something like `\newcommand*\cs[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}`).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the TeXbook, p. 213 [part of Chapter 20, "Definitions (also called Macros)"]:

> `\csname ... \endcsname`. When TeX expands `\csname` it reads to the matching `\endcsname`, expanding tokens as it goes; only character tokens should remain after this expansion has taken place. Then the "expansion" of the entire `\csname ... \endcsname` text will be a single control sequence token, defined to be like `\relax` if its meaning is currently undefined.

Several things to take away from this definition:

- Whereas "ordinary" TeX macro names must consist of either *exactly one non-letter* character -- e.g., `\,`, `\!`, and `\/` -- or *one or more letters* (more precisely, characters that have category code "letter" (11), usually `A-Z` and `a-z`) -- e.g., `\relax` and `\kern` -- the `\csname ... \endcsname` method lets you create macro names that can contain characters -- including whitespace and (isolated) backslash characters -- that are not be permitted by the rules of TeX syntax.
- The main restriction on the use of the `\csname ... \endcsname` method is that what's between `\csname` and `\endcsname` must be expandable to yield "character tokens". Hence, unexpandable tokens (such as TeX "primitive" control sequence tokens, e.g., `\kern` and `\vcenter`) are *not permitted*.

There are many uses for this method.

Answer (score 3):

Section 11.6 of [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) contains the following:

> With `\csname` it is possible to construct control sequences that cannot
>   ordinarily be written, because the constituent character tokens may
>   have another category than 11, letter.

A simple example (again from TeX by Topic) is

```
\csname a b\endcsname
```

There are many other applications; often `\csname` and `\endcsname` are used in the automatic construction of macros.

Answer (score 2):

`\cs` is only a command use to documente a command, in a handbook of package. It's used to :

- change typo
- index command
- add automatically the backslash

If you want to create a command dynamically, you should use :

- or `\csname` `endcsname` pair : `\expandfter\def\csname toto\endcsname{content}`. That create a `\toto` command.
- or easier, use the `\csdef` command of the `etoolbox` package : `\csdef{toto}{content}`