# Get the current citation counter value

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm working on a paper where the default citation style is a super script.

But in some parts of my text i like to put something like this:

....then more info see Ref[23].....

so in my doc with the paper bib style i get

[image]

what i want is get this

[image]

of course i can do it by hand but I'm wondering if there is an equivalent of \theequation coomand, thus I can type something like:

```
some text\cite{ref23} ..... see also [\thecite]
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). In this case it would  be helpful to see how you can achieve what you want "by hand".

Comment: This really depends on the citation package you might be using. You could try to mimic what `\cite` does using `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getcitenumber}[1]{\@ifundefined{b@#1}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}}{\csname b@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother` and then using `\getcitenumber{<cite>}` wherever you need the number printed, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional `\cite{<cite>}` command tests for the existence of a macro `\b@<cite>` - yes, a citation is just a macro definition. The test is necessary because, like [the `\label`-`\ref` system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764), it uses the `.aux` file for handling them and could be non-existent depending on your compilation. However, if the macro `\b@<cite>` exists, it sets it using a [`\csname`...`\endcsname` construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/5764). We can mimic this with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getcitenumber}[1]{% \getcitenumber{<cite>}
  \@ifundefined{b@#1}% Check if <cite> exists
    {\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}}% <cite> doesn't exist; print ?
    {\csname b@#1\endcsname}}% <cite> exists; print `\b@<cite>
\makeatother
```

and use `\getcitenumber{<cite>}` wherever you wish to print the citation.

The above suggestion may be heavily dependent on the citation package you're using.

Comment: I found the answer of you a couple of days ago and it was working like a charm.  However, now, sometimes it works, sometimes not on overleaf? To make it work again: select your code -> ctrl +c -> delete -> ctrl+v. weird.