# Redefine DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-operators

I'm looking for a way to replace `\DeclareMathOperator{\Operator}{Operator}` by something which would resemble `\MathOperator{Operator}`. I tried to define a new command `\newcommand\MathOperator[1]{\DeclareMathOperator{\#1}{#1}}` and then call it `\MathOperator{MyOperator}` but this doesn't seem to work, I got the following error: `"Undefined control sequence."` when calling `$\MyOperator$`. Any idea what I should do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show a full but minimal example of this. Your question is a bit difficult to understand. You never define `\MyOperator` above. That's for sure.

Comment: I suspect that `\#1` is understand by TeX as 2 tokens, not as 1. I'm no expert though.

Comment: You should use `\csname #1\endcsname` instead of `\#1`. See [What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/5764)

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for this thread, I missed it I guess. I'm still a bit concerned though: when I copy paste the code from the accepted answer, I get the following error message `"! Argument of \DeclareMyOperator has an extra }."` when calling `\DeclareMathOperators{Rep,Tet,Maps,Diff}`, any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that you copied the code properly as it works for me.

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure, thanks for your answer anyway, the problem comes from me for sure, I'll try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It seems what causes the problem on my computer is `\forcsvlist`, I have no idea why. But the exact and complete answer I was looking for is indeed what @Andrew pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think it is a good idea to redefine `\DeclareMathOperator` but rather make your own macro to create operatornames. One method would be to use `etoolbox` and use

```
\newcommand\myDeclareMathOperator[1]{\csdef{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}
```

Note that some names are just not good names for macros, for example you will burn your self on this one: `\myDeclareMathOperator{span}`

This one is a little safer

```
\newcommand\myDeclareMathOperator[1]{
  \ifcsundef{#1}{
    \csdef{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}
  }{
   \PackageError{MyMacros}{#1 is already used as a macro name}{}
  }
}
```

and if we in addition use `xparse` we can support the `*` notation:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myDeclareMathOperator{ s m }{
  \ifcsundef{#2}{
    \csdef{#2}{
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\operatorname*}{\operatorname}{#2}
    }
  }{
   \PackageError{MyMacros}{#2 is already used as a macro name}{}
  }
}
```

Comment: @GViaud, I've added a few additions