# Expanding macros within \csname

Tags: macros

I have some macros that expand to some text but when used together they should expand to something completely different. In this example:

- `\foo` -> `x`
- `\bar` -> `y`
- `\foo\bar` -> `Hello World`

Doing it with `\if...` constructions works in principle, but requires a lot of typing, so I tried it with `\csname`, but couldn't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand\ifalternatetext[2]{\ifnumcomp{\value{mycounter}}{>}{0}{\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}#1}{#2}}

\def\foo{\addtocounter{mycounter}{1}x}
\def\bar{\ifalternatetext{y}{z}}

\def\bazxy{Hello World}

\newcommand\print[2]{\csname baz#1#2\endcsname{}}

\begin{document}
This works: `\print{x}{y}'

This doesn't: `\print{\foo}{\bar}'
\end{document}
```

Comment: Omit the `{}` after `\foo{}` and `\bar{}`

Comment: Works for the example as originally posted, but not for the real document, modified the example to reflect this.

Comment: I don't see how is `\emph` a good thing to put inside `\csname`. [What do you really want?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean)

Comment: Right. That was a case of "cutting away too much on the way to the MWE", using `\emph` instead of the counter stuff I actually have there. Causes the same message (and what I really want is that message not appearing anymore), but is confusing to the reader. Modified it accordingly.

Comment: @user66554: My solution worked right out of the box... if you changed the question/code it's quite natural that in most cases a provided solution will not work any longer. What do you expect me do now?

Comment: you can't have font commands (or any other non-expandable command) in a csname, What do you want it to do?

Comment: See my answer to [What exactly do `\csname` and `\endcsname` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/), in particular the passage “It's possible to give many other interesting uses of this trick. But one should always keep in mind that TeX does *complete expansion* of what it finds in that context and that *only characters* must remain.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting `\foo` and `\bar` directly into the `\csname` I now have `\foo` and `\bar` assign a temporary macro which then can be used within `\csname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{@mycounter}

\makeatletter

\def\@foo@out{}
\def\@bar@out{}

\newcommand\ifalternatetext[2]{%
    \ifnumcomp{\value{@mycounter}}{>}{0}{%
    \addtocounter{@mycounter}{-1}%
    \gdef\@bar@out{#1}%
    }{%
    \gdef\@bar@out{#2}%
    }}

\newcommand\@foohelper[1]{%
    \addtocounter{@mycounter}{1}%
    \gdef\@foo@out{#1}%
    }

\def\foo{\@foohelper{x}}
\def\bar{\ifalternatetext{y}{z}}

\def\bazxy{Hello World}

\newcommand\print[2]{#1#2\csname baz\@foo@out\@bar@out\endcsname{}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
`\print{\foo}{\bar}'
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `{}` brackets after `\foo` and `\bar` prevent the expansion of the the macros in the OP's second call to `\print`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo{x}
\def\bar{y}

\def\bazxy{Hello World}

\newcommand\print[2]{\csname baz#1#2\endcsname{}}

\begin{document}
This works: `\print{x}{y}'

This also works: `\print{\foo}{\bar}'
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, for the version as originally posted - but that one did nothing instead of complaining `missing \endcsname` as in my original document. I managed to reproduce the behaviour by adding `\emph{}`, but now your solution doesn't work anymore. And what would I have done if `\foo` and `\bar` had taken arguments and should not have been followed by a space? (they don't, though the macros called within them do.)

Comment: @user66554: I will look later on

Answer (score 6):

You can't do assignments inside `\csname...\endcsname`. A good reference is [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/) and my answer to it where you find

> It's possible to give many other interesting uses of this trick. But one should always keep in mind that TeX does *complete expansion* of what it finds in that context and that *only characters* must remain.

Since `\addtocounter{mycounter}{1}` relies on eventually doing `\global\advance\c@mycounter by 1` it is not allowed in `\csname...\endcsname`.

If all you want is to have `\foo` behaving differently if followed by `\bar` or not, use `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifnextchar\baz{\foobaz\@gobble}{x}}
\newcommand{\baz}{y}
\newcommand{\foobaz}{Hello world}
\makeatother
```

Note that `\@gobble` will remove the superfluous `\baz` token.

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifnextchar\baz{\foobaz\@gobble}{x}}
\newcommand{\baz}{y}
\newcommand{\foobaz}{Hello world}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Separate: \foo{} and \baz.

Contiguous: \foo\baz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a different approach with your `\print` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}

\newcommand{\foo}{x\expandafter\@secondofthree}
\newcommand{\fuu}{T\expandafter\@secondofthree}
\newcommand{\baz}{\@secondoftwo{y}{z}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\bazz{Normal}
\newcommand\bazTy{Ops}
\newcommand\bazxy{Hello World}

\newcommand\print[2]{\csname baz#1#2\endcsname}

\begin{document}

`\print{\foo}{\baz}'

`\print{\fuu}{\baz}'

`\print{}{\baz}'

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\print{\foo}{\baz}` becomes

```
\csname baz\foo\baz\endcsname
```

and, expanding `\foo`.

```
\csname bazx\expandafter\@secondofthree\baz\endcsname
```

Now `\expandafter` causes the expansion of `\baz` and disappears

```
\csname bazx\@secondofthree\@secondoftwo{y}{z}\endcsname
```

where the expansion of `\@secondofthree` selects `y`, giving

```
\csname bazxy\endcsname
```

When `\print{}{\baz}` is used, we have

```
\csname baz\@secondoftwo{y}{z}\endcsname
```

and `\@secondoftwo` selects `z`, giving `\csname bazz\endcsname`.

One can install an abstraction layer that eventually does the same, but makes definitions easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}

\newcommand{\newprefixcommand}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{#2\expandafter\@secondofthree}%
}
\newcommand{\newalternatecommand}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\@secondoftwo{#2}{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\print[2]{\csname baz#1#2\endcsname}

\newprefixcommand{\foo}{x}
\newprefixcommand{\fuu}{T}
\newalternatecommand{\baz}{y}{z}

\newcommand\bazz{Normal}
\newcommand\bazTy{Ops}
\newcommand\bazxy{Hello World}

\begin{document}

`\print{\foo}{\baz}'

`\print{\fuu}{\baz}'

`\print{}{\baz}'

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are several dozen foos and bars each, making the `\if...`-based approach rather cumbersome. I thought I could use `\let` or something to evaluate `\foo\bar` to make the assignments and assign the result to a new, temporary macro containing no assignments which then could be used in `\csname`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @user66554 You have better ask a new question, stating precisely your aim, with a sensible minimal example.

Comment: @user66554 I added a different approach with your `\print` macro.