# Problem with \relax

Tags: expansion

I read a lot of stuff about `\relax` for 2 days but can't handle the following problem.

Why `\romanNumber` has no problem but `\romanNumberX` does not work? `\relax` 
must stop `\romannumeral` and not `\csname`. Please correct my vision about TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\romanNumber}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\romanNumberX}[1]{\romannumeral #1\relax}
\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname name\romanNumber{2}\endcsname{Must do!\\}
\nameii%OK, no problem here

%The following line generate error "missing \endcsname"
\expandafter\def\csname nameX\romanNumberX{2}\endcsname{Also must do!\\}%
\nameXii%Does not work, :(

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look e.g. the end of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39382/82917), or the quote from the TeX book of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39396/82917). Whatever comes between `\csname` and `\endcsname` should expand into _characters_.

Comment: Thanks a lot @campa, that was helpful. So is there any alternative for \relax in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\romanNumber}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
```

`\romanumeral` will parse ahead consuming any valid part of a `<number>` so

```
 \romanNumber{1}1
```

would convert 11 producing `xi` not convert 1 so expanding to `i1`

The parsing stops at any non expandable token that is not allowed in a `<number>` so you could use `\relax` but then

```
   \newcommand{\romanNumber}[1]{\romannumeral #1\relax}

 \romanNumber{1}1
```

expands to `i\relax 1` which isn't allowed in csname.

If the non expandable token that stops the number is a space it is *not* replaced so you could do

```
   \newcommand{\romanNumber}[1]{\romannumeral #1 }
```

then

```
 \romanNumber{1}1
```

expands to `i1`

But `\newcount\foo  \foo=1`

```
 \romanNumber{\foo}1
```

expands to `i 1` as `\foo` terminates the number itself so does not need the space so the space is not consumed.

using e-tex you can use

```
\newcommand{\romanNumber}[1]{\romannumeral\numexpr#1\relax}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle. It seems that I must use first version of \romanNumber.