# newcommand problems

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am working with \newcommand and \ifdefined. I have an issue with the below code as it produces an error and I don't know what is wrong:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\FailedReq}{
Nour
}

\newcommand{\ReqOpenIssues}{}

%\newcommand{\NoOpenIssues}{}

\newcommand{\OpenIssues}[1]{\ifcsname#1OpenIssues\endcsname \Failed#1 \else \ifdefined\NoOpenIssues NA \fi \fi 
}

\OpenIssues{Req}

\end{document}
```

Any help ?

Comment: the error is undefined command `\Failed`  you have that command in the definition but have not defined it, what do you want it to do?

Comment: oh did you want to execute `\FailedReq` ? you need \csname Failed#1\endcsname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same problem as in your previous question where you tried

```
\ifdefined\#1OpenIssues
```

in the hope that `\#1OpenIssues` becomes `\ReqOpenIssues` when the argument of the macro is `Req`.

Sorry, but TeX works with tokens that are formed at definition time. In that replacement text the tokens are

```
\ifdefined•\#•1•O•p•e•n•I•s•s•u•e•s
```

(the bullet just separates tokens for clarity). In particular that part of the replacement text never has `#•1` which marks the place for the argument substitution.

Similarly here

```
\Failed#1
```

is three tokens

```
\Failed•#•1
```

and the argument replacement yields

```
\Failed•R•e•q
```

(four tokens).

The primitive `\ifcsname` forms a control sequence name with the tokens up to the matching `\endcsname`; then it tests whether that control sequence is defined.

For the problem at hand you have to use the corresponding primitive that forms the control sequence and executes it, so

```
\csname Failed#1\endcsname
```

See [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/4427)

Answer (score 5):

if `#1` is `req` then   `\Failed#1`  is the same as `\Failed req` and gives an error that `\Failed` is undefined.

You intended to execute `\FailedReq` so to generate that command name you should replace `\Failed#1` by `\csname Failed#1\endcsname`