# Should we really use csname?

Tags: csname, coding

Over time have seen `csname` but I never *had to* learn it until now.

But after reading @egreg's (beautiful!) answer to [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do), I am not so sure if this is good coding.

Here is a test showing strange bahaviour:

1. `\csname endcsname`
2. `\csname endcsname \endcsname`
3. `\csname backslash endcsname\endcsname`

The first two worked as expected. i.e. they generated errors, but the last one gave no error. I would love to understand what I missed!?

(Certainly, there are pros: you may reuse code and you can tweak space etc.)

Comment: I assume you mean csname not cscode ???

Comment: `\csname..\endcsname` can be used nicely for triggering expansion. Besides this `\csname..\endcsname` can be used for creating control-word-tokens whose names contain characters which are not of category code 11(letter). TeX does tokenize `\ab12` as tokens `\ab`, `1`, `2`.  `\csname ab12\endcsname` yields a single control-word token `\ab12`.

Comment: the use of `\csname`  is for generating command tokens eg `\begin{...}`  is more or less defined to be `\begingroup\csname #1\endcsname`  as it needs to convert the environment name to a command. So if you are defining such a "meta" command you may need `\csname` if you are not, then you do not need it.

Comment: Try using expl3, most of the time you can get away with :c-type argument. (also try using LuaTeX, you don't need to understand what a control sequence is at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. `\csname endcsname`
> 2. `\csname endcsname \endcsname`
> 3. `\csname backslash endcsname\endcsname`

1 will give a missing `\endcsname` error if there is a non-character token (after expansion) before a following `\endscsname`

2 will define the command `endcsname<space>` to be `\relax` and then execute it, this is the behaviour for any undefiend command accessed by `\csname`.

3  will similarly define `backslash<space>endcsname` to be `\relax`

The actual question in the title (assuming you meant `\csname` not `cscode`) is probably "No.". That is, it is a very specialised command useful in some internal macro definition contexts, but shouldn't be used in a document.

Comment: Thanks,, yes i meant `csname` (I am a typo expert).

Comment: Btw... I would certainly accept your answer, but I will let it be open for now in order to see if someone else is triggered.

Comment: @AD. Typo expert? Welcome to the club! ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez actually I intended to write what I worte as I misread the question (even though I copied it to the answer) will fix, thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "actually I intended to write what I worte..." I envy you for that. With me it's different and much more chaotic: When I stop writing, I often ask myself: What the heck was I actually up to when I started writing? :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez but apparently I can't spell wrote

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aorccding to a sudty of a uvenirsity, it is not imrtpoant in which oredr the lerttes are in a wrod, the olny thnig taht is iomprtant is taht the frist and the lsat letter are in the rihgt potsiion. :-)

Comment: Both of you, thanks for givnig me a smlie :)