# What does “cs” mean in TeX

Tags: tex-core

this might be irrelevant question but what does cs mean in macros like `\csname` and `\endcsname`

This is my first question on SE, sorry for any mistakes i do, please correct me. Thanks

Comment: Control sequence

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cs` in `\csname`...`\endcsname` stands for `c`ontrol `s`equence.

You'll find some original reference to this definition in [The TeXbook](https://archive.org/download/B-001-002-139/Donald_Knuth_-_The_Tex_Book.pdf) (**Chapter 3 Controlling TeX**, p 7):

> Immediately after typing '`\`' (i.e., immediately after an escape character)
> you type a coded command telling TeX what you have in mind. Such commands
> are called *control sequences*.