# Cross-referencing custom labeled examples

Tags: cross-referencing, linguistics, linguex

I'm having trouble with `linguex` cross-referencing examples with an optional argument as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{linguex}
    \title{Title}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \a.[{\bf Optional Argument: }] Principle. \label{Principle}

    Here comes some text that references \ref{Principle}.

    \end{document}
```

Is there a way to get cross-references even when I'm using custom arguments?

Comment: You're missing the instruction `\ex.` that initiates the list-like environment.

Comment: @mico I think bozidarka wants the example to be unnumbered but still referable in some way.  If this is the case, then [How does one set custom labels for description lists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167) might be of some use.

Comment: @AlanMunn - You may well be correct. Let's see what the OP writes.

Comment: @Mico@AlanMunn Yes, I don't want the example to be numbered. The idea is to have a custom name (in my case "Optional Argument"), and then to be able to refer back to it (what I tried to do with the `\label{Principle}` `\ref{Principle}` command. `linguex` allows you to have a custom argument, but I can't figure out if it allows you to cross-reference it correctly.

Comment: What should the reference return? The contents of the optional argument? Or something else altogether?