# Automatic clickable links directly to the description labels

Tags: hyperref, description

For the university I am composing a document of only definitions, containing all the definitions of difficult terms that I encounter while studying. The document actually is a large set of description environments, separated only by the sections that group the entries according to the chapters of the reference book. Moreover I am inserting many clickable links that refer to various items of the text, both because some terms have a very widespread synonym (which therefore I have to insert as a separate item but that actually refers only to the main term) and because, sometimes, in the text of a definition I use a term which is then explained in another entry and which is therefore convenient to link with a clickable link.

Since each term is unique and all are inserted inside the square brackets typical of the description environments, it is possible to create a command that, with a simple syntax like `\go_to{term_xy}`, tells LaTeX to connect to the only point of the source where is the string `[term_xy]`? Thus the creation of the interlinks would be greatly facilitated, above all because I could avoid replacing the already compiled entries with `\hypertarget{term_xy}{term_xy}`.

Below is an example of how I create links now:

```
item [\hypertarget{peptidoglycan}{Peptidoglycan}] definition...
other items ...
item [Murein] see $rightarrow$ \hyperlink{peptidoglycan}{peptidoglycan}
```

I'm open also for advices that bypass the problem

Comment: The solution presented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/293/134144  should also work for your case.

Comment: Thanks! The answer you linked me is very useful, sorry if I haven't seen it previously. But is there any way to make the `\descref{}` command case-insensitive? Since all the `\descitem{}` begins with capital letter and I always have to reference to them in the middle of a definition (where the lowercase letter is required), I think it would be great if I can cross-reference regardless of upper or lower case.

Comment: @andreagoo8: I think the easiest way is to NOT play around with the labels but with the commands. First, if all the `\descitem{}`s are going to be capitalized, you can make sure to always type the label with **lower** case initials but use the `mfirstuc` package to capitalize the first letter when displaying the term. And then you can also define `\Descref{}` which will print the term with capitalization using the same trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works great. One last problem that i hadn't detected yet: sometimes I have to put some words of the label in italic (but not all). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Stack Exchange, and I don't know if I should edit the question rather than write here in the comments