# Creating custom enumeration

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, linguistics

This question must have been asked before, but I couldn't find anything. How would I create lists like this one:

```
(1) This    is     a      sentence                               (Note 1) 
    Gloss1  Gloss2 Gloss3 Gloss4     
    'This is a sentence'                      

(2a) yyy                                                         (Note 2a)

(2b) zzz                                                         (Note 2b)

(2c) uuu                                                         (Note 2c)

(3) qqq                                                          (Note 3)

(3') www                                                         (Note 3')

(4) ttt                                                          (Note 4)
```

in a way that I can refer to all those bullet points like (3') or (2b) both before and after they appear and also that allows those "www", "yyy", etc. to be three-line glosses, as in (1)? I can probably do all the labels "1", "2a", etc. manually, but I was wondering if this can be at least partially automated.

Comment: Is there a system in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkusG. No, I guess I'm not tied to anything.

Comment: What are the purposes of the parentheticals on the right? Is there a reason why you have a numbered list on the left that has additional numbering on the right?

Comment: If the emphasis is on nonlinear/arbitrary labeling of items and cross references, maybe the answers (not so much the question itself) to this post can help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-to-cross-reference-items-in-description-lists

Comment: @WillieWong "Note 1" etc. could be the name of the language in which the sentence is written, or the name of the construction used in the sentence, or the source of the sentence. The numbers on the right don't matter.

Comment: Do you want help with the whole layout, or just how to do the cross-referencing? With the example you showed I don't see an obvious pattern that would allow automatically generating the labels. Throwing together just the cross referencing part is not too hard, if you are willing to label everything by hand. If you have some rules then it may be possible to programmatically include them. For example, if there are only three types of labels (numeric, numeric+alpha, numeric+prime), then it is probably possible to generate the numeric parts automatically.

Comment: ... if the numeric part only either increase or stay the same from item to item.

Comment: I think it might be easier for me to just use "sub-lists"... Probably the question I asked is too broad.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the linked question. If it's not, please explain how what you want to do is fundamentally different from what any of the linguistics packages can do.